# Does anyone know the difference between endl(cout) and cout << endl?

Tags: c++, cout, endl

I thought they were the same thing, but when I sent a code to an online judge (with `endl(cout)`) it gave me "Wrong answer" verdict, then I tried to send another with `cout << endl` and the judge accepted the code! Does anyone know the difference between those commands?

Comment: If you have `using std::cout` then the first form will compile but the second won't (due to argument dependent lookup). I can't think of cases where the second form works but the first does not as is the case with the online judge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none that I know of.

`std::endl` is a function that take a stream and return a stream:

```
ostream& endl ( ostream& os );
```

When you apply it to `std::cout`, it just applies the function right away.

On the other hand, `std::basic_ostream` has an overload of `operator<<` with the signature:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
basic_ostream<C,T>& operator<<(basic_ostream<C,T>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<C,T>&));
```

which will also apply the function right away.

So, technically, there is no difference, even though stream `std::cout << std::endl` is more idiomatic. It could be that the judge bot is simplistic though, and does not realizes it.

Comment: I guess the only difference is that there are two function calls instead of one with `cout << endl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! in the future I will be using only cout << endl :)

Comment: Wait, `endl` shouldn't convert to `ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&)`, IIRC there is another overload.

Comment: `endl` cannot be converted to a `ios_base& ( *pf )(ios_base&)` because its parameter and return type have to be a `basic_ostream` specialization. `basic_ostream` has a template member: `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&));`, though.
`

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that `endl(cout)` is considered as a global function whereas in `cout << endl`, `endl` is considered as a manipulator. But they have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in behaviour between those two forms. Both refer to the same `endl` function, which can be used as a manipulator (`cout << endl`) or as a free function (`endl(cout)`).

Answer (score 1):

Answers above are correct! Also, Depending whether you use `<< endl;` or `endl(cout)` it could reduce the number of lines in your code.

Example:

You can have something like:

`cout << "Hello World" << endl;`

OR

`cout << "Hello World";`

`endl(cout);`

HOWEVER,
`cout << "Hello World" << endl(cout);` //Does NOT work

So it is 2 lines vs 1 line in this example.